# How to display an iOS 5 notification?

Tags: iphone, ios5, notifications

I would display a notification banner when I push an UIButton.

Maybe there is already an answer, but I didn't find.

Comment: Not possible. That action is not within the scope of a notification. You can use UIAlertView instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a notification banner for that, but [this library (Tapku Library)](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-alerts-with-images) has a pretty cool alert view which you can modify to fit your needs!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use UIAlertView or make your own custom view